# python nesting brackets

Tags: python

PHP uses brackets to nest functions, loops, if statements, etc. eg

```
function somefunction(){
    for($i = 0; $i < somenumber; ++$i){
    }
}
```

Python instead uses indents to nest.   Is there an alternative to nesting without indents in Python?

Comment: You mean an alternative to indenting blocks?

Comment: Semicolons. But you're not supposed to because that's not “nesting” of anything.

Comment: Try this to see: `from __future__ import braces`

Comment: That is the crux of Python - Readability. If you need something as an alternative, I'd rather suggest trying some other Language altogether.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  That's how python works.  You use indentation to specify block level.